# Using CodePipeline - deploy a CloudFormation stack to another account

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I am configuring a CodePipeline in Account 00000000000.

I would like to deploy a CloudFormation stack

- by executing a CloudFromation template via the CodePipeline
- but in account 123456789123 and not in 00000000000

**Question**

How do I configure the CodePipeline action of type "Deploy" to do so? 
Especially how do I point it to account 123456789123?

**What I did so far**

I assume it works via IAM roles 123456789123.

I created an IAM role in account 123456789123, 
with trust to the account 00000000000, 
with trust to the service cloudformation.  
I named it `arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/CFDep`

Below is the configuration of my CodePipeline-Action.
I am getting an error `The role name is invalid. Check that the specified role exists and can be assumed by AWS CloudFormation.` Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html#pipelines-create-cross-account-create):

> **You cannot use the AWS CodePipeline console to create or edit a
>   pipeline that uses resources associated with another AWS account.**
>   However, you can use the console to create the general structure of
>   the pipeline, and then use the AWS CLI to edit the pipeline and add
>   those resources. Alternatively, you can use the structure of an
>   existing pipeline and manually add the resources to it.

You can do one of the following 2 things:

1. **Use [aws codepipeline cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codepipeline/update-pipeline.html) to edit the pipeline**

   `aws codepipeline update-pipeline --cli-input-json file://pipeline.json`

   OR
2. **Create the pipeline itself using cloudformation**

   You can use [this pipeline definition](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-refarch-cross-account-pipeline/blob/master/ToolsAcct/code-pipeline.yaml) from aws reference architecture for cross account pipeline as a starting point for your template.